# unable to create an implicit read for JSON

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

My server code will receive the following `JSON`

```
{
    "signin-info":{
        "email" : "someemail",
        "password": "password"
    }
}
```

I have created the following 2 case classes to represent this structure.

```
case class UserSigninInfo(
  email:String,
  password:String
)
case class UserSignin(
  signinInfo: UserSigninInfo
)
```

To read the JSON, I have created the following 2 `Reads`

```
  implicit val userSigninInfoReads:Reads[UserSigninInfo] = (
    (JsPath \ "email").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "password").read[String]
  )(UserSigninInfo.apply _)

  implicit val userSigninReads:Reads[UserSignin] = (
    (JsPath \ "signin-info").read[UserSigninInfo]
  )(UserSignin.apply _)
```

But for `userSigninReads`, I am getting the following compilation error. What am I doing wrong?

```
overloaded method value read with alternatives:
[error]   (t: models.UserSigninInfo)play.api.libs.json.Reads[models.UserSigninInfo] <and>
[error]   (implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[models.UserSigninInfo])play.api.libs.json.Reads[models.UserSigninInfo]
[error]  cannot be applied to (models.UserSigninInfo => models.UserSignin)
[error]     (JsPath \ "signin-info").read[UserSigninInfo]
[error]                                 `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to construct reads for your main object is:

```
implicit val userSigninReads : Reads[UserSignin] =
  (JsPath \ "signin-info").read[UserSigninInfo].map(UserSignin(_))
```

This is because it only has a single field.

Your construction was essentailly:

```
((JsPath \ "signin-info").read[UserSigninInfo])(UserSignin.apply _)
```

which is simply

```
(JsPath \ "signin-info").read[UserSigninInfo](UserSignin.apply _)
```

because it just adds extra `()`.

`read` method indeed has two alternatives:

```
def read[T](t: T) = Reads.pure(t)
def read[T](implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[T] = Reads.at[T](this)(r)
```

It expects either implicit reads or explicit value, but you are passing a function, this is why compiler complains.

When you combine multiple fields with `and`, different object is created, e.g. `FunctionalBuilder[M]#CanBuild2[A, B]` for 2 elements, and it has `apply` method to construct final `Reads` instance.

As you only have one object you can create your `Reads` by reading `UserSigninInfo` from the path you want and putting the result into `UserSignin` with `map`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it. I did observe that the code works if I add another field and use `and`. I couldn't understand the logic though. Look forward to your further explanation

Comment: Thanks. it worked. So `(JsPath \ "signin-info").read[UserSigninInfo]` returns `Reads[UserSigninInfo]`. The `map` of `Reads` returns an object of type `UserSigninInfo` which is passed to `UserSignin` (i.e. `Reads[UserSigninInfo].map(x:UserSigninInfo=>UserSigninInfo.apply(s))`?

Comment: I wouldn't use exactly those words, but pretty much yes (except for I guess the typo in your last snippet, info shouldn't be there in `apply` part). `map` is a function that can transform `Reads[A]` into `Reads[B]` given `A => B`. So map takes a function `UserSigninInfo => UserSignin`. `map` allows us to get our hands on the `UserSigninInfo` object, so that we can wrap it into `UserSignin` resulting in Reads[UserSignin].